# Remove GUI from fedora 36

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel, python, gui

I would like to remove GUI from Fedora 36,Because I will use only terminal ,and I do not need GUI.Is there any way to do that using terminal.
Then I will make my own desktop using python.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use Gnome? You could install any simple Window Manager or boot into a plain X.org session without any window manager at all. I've no idea how you will work with windows because you won't be able to resize/move/activate/deactive them. What's "my own desktop using python"?

Comment: yeah , I want to  remove Gnome from Fedora XD.

Comment: but, How can do that?

Comment: you can uninstall the software (dnf remove lots of software), or just disable gdm, which starts the gui ( `systemctl disable gdm` )

Comment: thanks, it is helped